# How to use OneDrive on Ubuntu with symbolic links

Tags: ubuntu, cloud, onedrive, symlink, cloud-storage

I'm syncing the folder `/home/user/OneDrive`. Inside the folder there is a symbolic link `/home/user/OneDrive/A`.

I want to sync the actual file that `A` is pointing to, instead of the symbolic link itself, so that I have a backup of `A`.

How do I achieve this using Ubuntu? I have googled this to no avail. Insync definitely doesn't work. Microsoft Support would have no idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible using the `rclone` package with the `--copy-links` flag when running the `rclone sync` or `rclone copy` command.

Answer (score 0):

The current version of OneDrive Client for Linux (v2.4.25-1+np1) does this natively.